# Python Ifstatement SyntaxError:Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I'm using the following code, but I've got syntax error on the `if` statement  pointing to the zero. I tried to change any part of the `if` statement to make it work, but couldn't solve it. Any ideas?

```
if taken[tmpIndex] == 0
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's the entire code:

```
for i in range(0, items):
    tmpLarge = nth_largest(i+1, ratio)
    tmpIndex = ratio.index(tmpLarge)
    if taken[tmpIndex] == 0
        taken[tmpIndex] = 1
        leftCapacity -= tmpLarge
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a colon, like this

```
if taken[tmpIndex] == 0:
```

Comment: thanks, i feel incredibly stupid now... but my problem solved

Comment: thanks :). i tried that, I have to wait for 6 minutes before ticking.

Answer (score 2):

You're [missing a colon](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements):

```
if taken[tmpIndex] == 0:
```